# Mocha file 404 test js front end

Tags: mocha.js

I'm trying to implement this tutorial by the way
https://blog.codeship.com/mocha-js-chai-sinon-frontend-javascript-code-testing-tutorial/

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/raw/master/mocha.js

but in file mocha.js i found a 404...
Can someone help me and provide this file to put on front end...

I couldn't found the right one as equal to work on it.

Many thanks
Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 0):

I already solved...
I have checked the version and then applied...

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mocha/1.16.0
Done

Thanks
Carlos Vieira